# Running a script as a webpage

Tags: bash, shell-script, html

So I've got basically the most rudimentary understanding of how webpages work, I installed httpd, apache, php and some other stuff, and now if I put files in `/var/www/html` people can access them by going to `xx.xx.xx.xx/FILENAME`

Now what I'm trying to do is, have a script be run on that page for everybody accessing it. It's a script that takes user input as well (you know, with the `read` command).

How would I do that? Is there any way to basically 'emulate' a bash environment on the web page? Also my script requires a file that's in the same folder as the script (which is `/var/www/html`).

Also I'm well aware of the security issues, but this is just a proof of concept... kinda… so security isn't that important.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Do you mean to execute a _shell  script_ (for example a `bash` script) when a user access some web page? And it gets user input from `stdin`?

Comment: Are you wanting to implement an interactive shell CGI script?

Comment: I want it to be run as you would run the script normally from the command line.